# I am getting the following all of a sudden

Tags: laravel-5.1

**EDIT** **THE PACKAGE NO LONGER WORKS DUE TO AN UPGRADE FROM LARAVEL. THIS COMES STRAIGHT FROM THE DEVELOPER OF THE PACKAGE "ELOQUENCE"**

I have done nothing to my code. All of a sudden I try to use the search field and get this error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select count(*) 
 as aggregate   from 
(select `posts`.*, max(case when `posts`.`title` = ? then 15 else 0 
 end     + case when `posts`.`title` like ? then 5 else 0 end + case 
 when    `posts`.`title` like ? then 1 else 0 end + case when
 `posts`.`subtitle` = ?    then 15 else 0 end + case when 
 `posts`.`subtitle` like ? then 5 else 0 end + case when       
 `posts`.`subtitle` like ? then 1 else 0 end + case when 
  `posts`.`content_raw` = ? then 15 else 0 end + case when    
  `posts`.`content_raw` like ? then 5 else 0 end + case when   
  `posts`.`content_raw` like ? then 1 else 0 end + case when   
 `tags`.`title` = ? then 15 else 0 end + case when `tags`.`title` like   
? then 5 else 0 end + case when `tags`.`title` like ? then 1 else 0  
end) as relevance from `posts` left join `taggables` on  
`taggables`.`taggable_id` = `posts`.`id` left join `tags` on   
 `taggables`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` where (`posts`.`title` like ? or  
 `posts`.`subtitle` like ? or `posts`.`content_raw` like ? or  
 `tags`.`title` like ?) group by `posts`.`id`) as `posts` where    
 `relevance` >= 1)
```

I don't know whats going on. While writing this I updated the jarektkaczyk/eloquence package that i use for searches and nothing atill has happened. Was working fine and now this

Comment: What's your database's Collation? Make sure its `utf8_unicode_ci`. And the `?`s in your query are the bindings, check to see if any special characters are passed.

Comment: @kishanterry it was recently brought to my attention that laravel 5.1 has broken the package Eloquence. This is straight from the author of that package. there was no error on my part. This is why I don't like to use packages

Comment: thanks for the update